# Bootstrap Toggle not working on onclick LI element

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I'm using the bootstraptoggle from http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ to convert checkboxes into toggles. I have included their cdn for the script and the css.

https://jsfiddle.net/j04x6sjm/4/

On the `<li>one</li>` I have called the toggle function by `<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" />` but for some reason its not showing in the filldle. It works locally though. So what I want to achieve is to be able to check/uncheck the checkboxes on clicking the `<li>` or the checkbox itself. I'm able to achieve that for normal checkboxes with the script in the fiddle. How can I apply it to the toggled checkboxes too? The toggled class checkboxes should also be checked/unchecked on the corresponding `<li>` click.

Many thanks.

Comment: I think OP's talking about the converting the checkbox to switch like toggle control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not properly importing the `CSS`s. I've imported them and now it's working. You can manually toggle the switch using `.bootstrapToggle('toggle')` method(from official page).

```js
$('.list-group-item1-text').click(function() {  
    var $cb = $(this).parent().find(":checkbox");
    $cb.bootstrapToggle('toggle');
    //if (!$cb.prop("checked")) {
      //  $cb.prop("checked", true);
    //} else {
    //    $cb.prop("checked", false);
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group1">
  <li class="list-group-item1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" />
    <span class="list-group-item1-text" >One</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" />
    <span class="list-group-item1-text">Two</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" />
    <span class="list-group-item1-text">Three</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" />
    <span class="list-group-item1-text">Four</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" />
    <span class="list-group-item1-text">Five</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for fixing the css. how do I convert the switch toggle which is based on checked / not checked. Thanks

Comment: I am kind of confuse. Can you explain a little more

Comment: You see i have used the `<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" />` for `<li>One</li>` and it works if you click on the actual checkbox or the switch (not sure if its called that). The On and Off switch. So its On when checkbox is checked. So I want it to toggle as well when I click on the `<li>` which has that. In this case, the `<li>One`

Comment: Thanks a million. So i should have avoided using `if (!$cb.prop("checked")) {
      $cb.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
       $cb.prop("checked", false);`

Thanks again mate!!

Comment: Most welcome!!! I won't say avoid but If you like this way, do this way..

Comment: mate .. umm .. there is a small problem .. the actual switch is not clickable. Its triggered only on the `<li>` click and not the actual switch click .. could you just have a look plz?

Comment: its applied to the text and not the `<li>`   :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120439/discussion-between-jonju-and-somename).

Answer (score 1):

Before fix your jquery....

```
$('ul.list-group1 li').on('click', function() {
 var $cb = $(this).find(":checkbox");
 if (!$cb.prop("checked")) {
    $cb.prop("checked", true);
 } else {
    $cb.prop("checked", false);
 }
});

$('ul.list-group1 li input').on('click', function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```